# find Kth element in a Binary Search tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I'm learning about Binary Search Trees. I want to return the k-th element of the in-order traversal of the binary search tree. How can I keep the variable 'count' updated or is there some way to break out of the loop once I find the k-th element and print it out?

```
public void kthElement(int n, int count, BinaryNode<AnyType> root){

    if( root.left !=null)
        this.kthElement(n, count, root.left);

    count++;
    if(count==n){
        System.out.println(root.element); 
        }

    else if(count!=n){
        return;}

    if( root.right != null)
        this.kthElement(n, count, root.right);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions.

1. Declare a field for each node stating how many elements are in it's right subtree and left subtree, from here it should be easy to proceed.
2. If you're allowed to use additional memory, copy the elements to a dynamically allocated sorted array (using inorder traversal) and return the k'th element.

Comment: Ok I figured it out using the first suggestion... Took a little bit of thinking (and help from a friend)